# Anylogic: How can I add multiple agents (jobs) to one resource at the same time in Anylogic 8.0?

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

I am trying to add different jobs to one machine and I cannot use batch because the jobs are grouped based on different conditions. So I want to add the jobs to a resource based on the conditions and then add them to machines, which requires the resource to accept multiple jobs at the same time.

Comment: Your question doesn't provide enough specifics for anyone to really help you. This site is meant to help with specific programming issues. Have you tried to write any code yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is not how resources work in AnyLogic. Individual jobs (=agents) seize resources for themselves. **So 1 agent can seize several resources but 1 resource always works on 1 agent only at the same time!**

So either you pre-group your agents together manually (no need to use batch, you can group them manually yourself based on your conditions).

Or you replace resources (and all related seize,release,service blocks) with your own custom resource agents and your own scheduling/assignment/planning logic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Benjamin. Just to make sure, by pre-group manually you mean using a combination of wait and batch to batch jobs based on a condition? I am not aware of any other approach for that.

Comment: lots of ways are possible, depends on your actual system requirements. Best ask a new (specific) question. But I was referring to combining them manually without any blocks. Purely agent-based